# реализация задачи Java

Tags: java, база-данных, spring-mvc

Не хватает опыта для реализации задачи, прошу подскажите как быть.

Есть задача (к примеру):
 1. В базе есть несколько (+100) авто. Мне нужно им прикрепить номер заявки.
 2. Далее, нужно взять все данные(LIST)  авто и генерировать заявку в формате пдф.
 3. Далее, нужно сделать upload пдф файлы (по одному) на другой сервер(1) (через restApi) и получить fileID
 4. Далее, полученные fileID передать на другой сервер(2)(по одному) (через restApi)
 5. Далее, после передачи fileID сделать update в базе авто (что заявка отправлена)
 6. Далее, нужно в одну таблицу сделать insert для управляющего(заявка отправлена, владелец должен ответит на заявления хх.хх.хх числа)

Всё это уже сделано, но остаётся вопрос, что делать если какой то этап дал ошибку? как отменить всё остальное (т.е. пройденные этапы) или есть какой нибудь другой вариант.

Вот еще пример:
допустим есть какие то данные(LIST). Нужно записать их в несколько серверов к примеру 5 поэтапно, сначала 1 далее 2 далее 3-4-5. и с каждого сервера возвращается ответ(число) и этот ответ нужно добавить к данным и отправит далее по этапу. если какая то сервер при записи даст ошибку то отменить всё или продолжить с этого момента когда включится база.

Comment: Рисуйте диаграмму процесса и потоки исполнения и обработки ошибок (см. BPMN)

Comment: Как я понял у Вас все это должно происходить в режиме транзакции, значит сервера должны поддерживать откат. Далее ловите на каждом этапе ошибку и если есть, запоминаете, что за этап и выполняете для него написанный Вами откат. Если нужно потом повторить (после восстановления сервера) делаете себе пометку. Таким образом у Вас должны быть как минимум три исполняемых модуля: Обработка, Откат, Повтор.